# Apache CXF is unable to handle duplicate localnames

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate Java stubs for the new 3rd party service. It worked before with no problem but recently they have added a new method `verifyDataExistence` and `wsdl2java`
got failed with the following error (real names were changed):

```
Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding jaxb ...
wsdl2java -verbose -b jaxb-bindings.xml -client -d src https://othercompany.com/SOAP/TheirService/Services?wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 3.5.5
Jan 06, 2024 1:22:55 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services}GetList cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
Jan 06, 2024 1:22:55 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation {urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services}HandleInfo cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
WSDLToJava Error: Parameter: theirData already exists for method verifyDataExistence but of type com.othercompany.soap.myservice.services.VerifyDataExistenceType.TheirData instead of com.mycompany.soap.theirservice.services.VerifyDataExistenceResponseType.TheirData.  Use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter.
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Parameter: theirData already exists for method verifyDataExistence but of type com.othercompany.soap.myservice.services.VerifyDataExistenceType.TheirData instead of com.othercompany.soap.myservice.services.VerifyDataExistenceResponseType.TheirData.  Use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter.
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaMethod.addParameter(JavaMethod.java:178)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.ParameterProcessor.addParameter(ParameterProcessor.java:130)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.ParameterProcessor.processWrappedAbstractOutput(ParameterProcessor.java:482)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.ParameterProcessor.processWrappedOutput(ParameterProcessor.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.ParameterProcessor.buildParamModelsWithoutOrdering(ParameterProcessor.java:651)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.ParameterProcessor.process(ParameterProcessor.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.OperationProcessor.processMethod(OperationProcessor.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.OperationProcessor.process(OperationProcessor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.PortTypeProcessor.process(PortTypeProcessor.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.WSDLToJavaProcessor.wsdlDefinitionToJavaModel(WSDLToJavaProcessor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.WSDLToJavaProcessor.process(WSDLToJavaProcessor.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:274)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:402)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
```

Here is wsdl:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions
    targetNamespace="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="Services.xsd1.xsd"
                namespace="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetList">
        <wsdl:part name="GetListRequest"
            element="xsns:GetListRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetListResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="GetListResponse"
            element="xsns:GetListResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="HandleInfo">
        <wsdl:part name="HandleInfoRequest"
            element="xsns:HandleInfoRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="HandleInfoResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="HandleInfoResponse"
            element="xsns:HandleInfoResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="VerifyDataExistence">
        <wsdl:part name="VerifyDataExistence"
            element="xsns:VerifyDataExistence" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse"
            element="xsns:VerifyDataExistenceResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServicesType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetList">
            <wsdl:input name="GetListRequest"
                message="ns0:GetList" />
            <wsdl:output name="GetListResponse"
                message="ns0:GetListResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="HandleInfo">
            <wsdl:input name="HandleInfoRequest"
                message="ns0:HandleInfo" />
            <wsdl:output name="HandleInfoResponse"
                message="ns0:HandleInfoResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="VerifyDataExistence">
            <wsdl:input name="VerifyDataExistenceRequest"
                message="ns0:VerifyDataExistence" />
            <wsdl:output name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse"
                message="ns0:VerifyDataExistenceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServicesBindingSOAP"
        type="ns0:ServicesType">
        <soap11:binding
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
        <wsdl:operation name="GetList">
            <soap11:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#GetList"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="GetListRequest">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="GetListResponse">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="HandleInfo">
            <soap11:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#HandleInfo"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="HandleInfoRequest">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="HandleInfoResponse">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="VerifyDataExistence">
            <soap11:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#VerifyDataExistence"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="VerifyDataExistenceRequest">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse">
                <soap11:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServicesBindingSOAP12"
        type="ns0:ServicesType">
        <soap12:binding
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
        <wsdl:operation name="GetList">
            <soap12:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#GetList"
                soapActionRequired="false" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="GetRequest">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="GetListResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="HandleInfo">
            <soap12:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#HandleInfo"
                soapActionRequired="false" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="HandleInfoRequest">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="HandleInfoResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="VerifyDataExistence">
            <soap12:operation
                soapAction="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services#VerifyDataExistence"
                soapActionRequired="false" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="VerifyDataExistenceRequest">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ServicesService">
        <wsdl:port name="ServicesPortSOAP"
            binding="ns0:ServicesBindingSOAP">
            <soap11:address
                location="https://192.168.1.2:1234/one/SomeServlet/SOAP/TheirService/Services" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ServicesPortSOAP12"
            binding="ns0:ServicesBindingSOAP12">
            <soap12:address
                location="https://192.168.1.2:1234/one/SomeServlet/SOAP/TheirService/Services" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and the separate schema file:

```xml
<schema elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:TheirService:Services">
    <complexType name="GetListRequestType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="AppId" type="xsd:string" />
            <element minOccurs="0" name="DataCode" type="xsd:string" />
            <element minOccurs="0" name="DepId" type="xsd:string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="GetListRequest"
        type="tns:GetListRequestType" />
    <complexType name="GetListResponseType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Count" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="List">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Data">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="ItemNo" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="DataCode" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="Prefix" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="Year" type="xsd:string" />
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="ErrorList">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Error">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="Code" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="Desc" type="xsd:string" />
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="GetListResponse"
        type="nslt1:GetListResponseType" />
    
    <element name="HandleInfoRequest"
        type="tns:HandleInfoRequestType" />
    <complexType name="HandleInfoResponseType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="TheirData">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="DataCode" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="Prefix" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="Year" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="ItemNo" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="HandlingStatus" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorsList">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Error">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="Code" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="Desc" type="xsd:string" />
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="HandleInfoResponse"
        type="nslt1:HandleInfoResponseType" />
    <complexType name="VerifyDataExistenceType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="AppId" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="TheirData">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="DataCode" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="Prefix" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element minOccurs="0" name="Year" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="ItemNo" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="VerifyDataExistence"
        type="tns:VerifyDataExistenceType" />
    <complexType name="VerifyDataExistenceResponseType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="TheirData">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="ItemNo" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="DataCode" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="Prefix" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element minOccurs="0" name="Year" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="DataExists" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element name="ProcessingCompleted" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorList">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Error">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="Code" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <element name="Desc" type="xsd:string" />
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="VerifyDataExistenceResponse"
        type="nslt1:VerifyDataExistenceResponseType" />
</schema>
```

To customize the generation I already have jaxb-bindings.xml

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

According to suggestion from the error I tried to use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter like

```xml
    <jaxb:bindings node="//wsdl:message[@name='verifyDataExistenceRequest']/wsdl:part[@name='theirData']">
        <jaxb:property name="verifyExistenceRequestTheirData" />
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings node="//wsdl:message[@name='verifyDataExistenceResponse']/wsdl:part[@name='theirData']">
        <jaxb:property name="verifyExistenceResponseTheirData" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

But it does not work since the definition of verifyDataExistenceRequest and verifyDataExistenceResponse types are in the separate xml scheme file `https://othercompany.com/SOAP/TheirService/Services.xsd1.xsd`

Also I tried to play with `schemaLocation` attribute but it all fails.

Will appreciate any ideas how to make it work.
Thanks